# Windows 10: How enable 'NetBios' in 'Discovery Method' in Network Explorer

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I have 4 PCs in my home, thus exists a LAN (All connected through wireless)

- Mac
- HP (Windows 8)
- Acer (Windows 7 Ultimate)
- Asus (Windows 10 - `Home Edition`)

Mac, HP, and Acer can see in peace within the same network all the rest of PCs. It through the `Windows Network Explorer`.

- **Note** thus `HP` and `Acer` can see the `Mac`, and `Mac` can see these two mentioned and even the `Asus`

The problem is with `Asus`, it only can see the `HP` and `Acer` PCs, it never can   detect and see the `Mac`.

I spent 2 days trying to figure out what is the problem or find some difference about HP and Acer against the Asus.

Thanks to God, I found the following:

- HP and Acer has the following:

[image]

From above two important things:

- The drop list shows: NetBios, SSDP, WSD
- According to the list in the white part or background, I can confirm `SSDP` represents the router, `WSD` the windows machines (including the asus) and finally the `NetBios` (the shown in the bottom, represents the `Mac` pc)

Now, applying the same approach in `Windows 10` (Remember `Home Edition`) I have:

[image]

Only appears `SSDP` and `WSD`.

Thus how configure `Windows 10` to list the `NetBios` option?

Sharing the following too, it about `IPv4`:

- For `HP` and `Acer`

[image]

- Asus:

[image]

How you can see, the same configuration

**Update**: If I put in the *address bar* explicitly the `Mac` remote location, it works

[image]

Furthermore in the left pane of the `Windows Explorer` within the `Network` item then appears the `Mac` remote machine. If a new `Windows Explorer` is opened and is re scanned the network the 'problematic' scenario happens again, and is fix it once the `Mac` remote location is inserted in the *address bar*.

Comment: First, what interface is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HASR.png) from exactly?  Second, this sounds like case of a lack of NetBIOS support from the driver, if an option in the properties of an adapter is missing on one device but exists on another.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows Explorer -> Network and add the 'Discovery Method' column, such as "Name", "Category", "Workgroup"